# Why does not work debugging Angular application?

Tags: angular, debugging, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I select `JavaScript Debug` and write a local url: `https://test-app.lan:3009`. In the `Remote URLs of local` I find root folder of application (here is also `node_modules`), pointing out to her the same way URL: `https://test-app.lan:3009`.

As a result, the console in the debugger is visible, breakpoints are marked as working when the application module is loaded, but it does not stop at them. In fact, not a single breakpoint does work.

I have a version of the IntelliJ IDEA - 2017.3, Angular 5.x, TypeScript 2.6. On other projects (which are not Angular but written in TypeScript), there are no such problems.

What could be the problem? Someone faced a similar?

**P.S.**

First I thought that it problem might be in lazy load modules - but not, the main module (app.module) is also not debugging.

Comment: Try tying 'debugger', above the line you want the debugger to stop. Then recompile the project, and make sure that your browser's console is opened. It should work. If it doesn't work, then there's something wrong with your code, not debugger.

Comment: @masterfan Debug in browser works normal. It does not work in my IDE (I mean intellij idea debugger)

Comment: try refreshing browser page - are breakpoints hit?

Comment: @lena The problem was solved, see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was add `webpack://C:/myproject-dir` in the `Remote URLs of local` list instead `https://test-app.lan:3009`. It resolved my problem.